# NetworkX: Copy weights to new graph, weights are duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am trying to create a network using Python and networkx. I have edge data as tsv (node, node, weight):

```
1   2   34
1   4   23
1   5   25
2   4   46
2   5   90
2   12  4
...
```

and node data with arbitrary attributes (e.g. color, type, shape), also tsv:

```
1   red cat round
2   blue    mouse   round
3   green   rat triangle
4   yellow  trex    square
```

I want to combine this information to create one network. So far, everything works fine:

```
df = pd.read_csv('nodes.tsv', sep='\t') # using pandas to read
for idy, row in df.iterrows():
    G2.add_node(row[0], color = row[1], type = row[2], shape = row[3])
...
with open('edges.tsv','rb') as edges_file:
    G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(edges_file)
...
G2.add_weighted_edges_from(G.edges(data = True))
```

Here, **the last line is the problem**.

```
>>>print(str(G2.edges(data=True))[1:200])
[('1', '2', {'weight': {'weight': 34}}), ('1', '4', {'weight': {'weight': 23}})
```

**How can I remove these double 'weights'?** Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: for each dictionary say dict['weight'] = dict['weight']['weight'], not sure about specifics but that would work with some tuple manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `add_weighted_edges_from`, do

```
G2.add_edges_from(G.edges(data = True))
```

That is, remove the `weighted` part from the command.

The third entry of any tuple in `G.edges(data=True)` is a dict containing all the attributes of the edge.  `add_edges_from` will figure out that the edges are weighted from the fact that the edges are added in the form `(node1, node2, dict)` and will realize that the dict is the dict of attributes.

Using `add_weighted_edges_from` causes problems because it expects the input to be of the form `(node1, node2, weight)`.  So it's interpreting that weight to be the entire dict, rather than the contents of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `nx.read_weighted_edgelist`. Using `nx.read_edgelist` will read it in properly so you only have `{'weight': 34}`, etc.

Alternatively, you may have control over how `edges.tsv` was created. In general, pair `nx.read_weighted_edgelist` with `nx.write_weighted_edgelist` and `nx.read_edgelist` with `nx.write_edgelist`.